# Does all the possible unions of (no) countable element from a no countable partition of a set define a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, set-partition

Is it correct to say that $ \left \{ \left \{ x \right \}, s.t. 0\leq x\leq 1 \right \}$  is a partition of $[0;1]$. (Using this partition definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Definition_and_Notation )
And that: $ B([0;1])=\sigma (\left \{ x \right \}, s.t. 0\leq x\leq 1) $.

More over in this case can we writte: $ \forall F \in B([0;1])  \exists {\alpha_{k \in \mathbb{R}}} \: s.t. \: \forall k  \: , \alpha_k \in \: \left \{ 0;1 \right \}$ such that $ F=\bigcup_{k \in [0;1]}^{} \alpha_k (\left \{ x \right \}) $

That means that $ \forall F \in B([0;1]) $ , F can be describe by an union, countable or not, of element from the partition $\left \{ \left \{ x \right \}, s.t. 0\leq x\leq 1 \right \}$ of $B([0;1])$?

And more generaly does for every set $\sigma(S)$ it exists a partition $P$ of $S$ such that $\forall F \in\sigma(S)$ can be describe by an union of element from $P$?

Comment: No for both question.

Comment: @Surb Why $P = { 0 \leq x \leq 1}$ is not a partition of $[0;1]$ ? Because it seems to respect the definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Comment: Because a partition has to be a countable collection of set, which is not the case of $(\{x\})_{x\in [0,1]}$.

Comment: @Surb Sorry but i don't see that a partition has to be countable in the defition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Definition_and_Notation And ({x})x∈[0,1] seems to hold the 3 criteria of the definition.

Comment: it's indeed true... according to your definition (or the one of wikipédia), $(\{x\})_{x\in [0,1]}$ is indeed a partition...

Comment: @Surb Thank a lot for your answer. So does my segond statement is also true? (Concerning the fact that each element of $B([0;1])$ can be describe as an union of element of the partition ({x})x∈[0,1] ?

Comment: no it's not, for exemple,  $[0,1]\notin \sigma (\{x\}:x\in [0,1])$ or for example, this $\sigma -$algebra contain none open set but the empty set.

Comment: @Surb Why do you say that "this σ−algebra contain none open set but the empty set." Indeed i.e $(1/4;1/2)=\bigcup_{1/4<x<1/2}^{}x=\bigcup_{0 \leq k \leq 1}^{}\alpha_k x, \: s.t. \: \alpha_k=1 \Leftrightarrow 1/4<x<1/2 \: if \: not \: \alpha_k=0$ ? same for $[0;1]=\bigcup_{0 \leq x \leq 1}^{}x$ ?

Comment: The smallest $\sigma -$algebra that contain $\mathcal A:=\{\{x\}\mid x\in [0,1]\}$ is the set that contain only countable union and countable intersection of element of $\mathcal A$. So, $$\sigma (\mathcal A)=\{P\subset [0,1]: P\text{ countable}\}.$$

Comment: @Surb thk. But is this correct? $∀ F∈B([0;1]), ∃α_{0 \leq k \leq 1}s.t.∀k,α_k∈{0;1}$ such that $F=⋃_{k∈[0;1]} α_k({x})$

Comment: I don't understand... $\alpha _k$ are numbers, not sets...